# AndEngine - can't iterate through array items inside handler calls

Tags: android, andengine

I am having a problem working inside a handler call. The problem is something as follows:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite[spriteArrayLength];
IUpdateHandler mm[i] = new ........// you know what
for(int i = 0; i < spriteArrayLength; i++){
   //many other actions
   mm[i] = new IUpdateHandler() {

       //do somthing with sprite array items
       float anyVar = sprite[i].getX();//problem rises here
   };
   sprite[i].registerUpdateHandler(mm[i]);
}
```

Every time it shows an error saying i reaches out of array bound. That means the handler call executes after for loop ends and so i already crosses its limit. How can I do something like above in a proper way?

**Edit:**

Sorry for my previous mistake. The First line of the code will be:

```
Sprite sprite[] = new Sprite[spriteArrayLength];
IUpdateHandler mm[] = new ........// you know what
```

not this:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite[spriteArrayLength];
IUpdateHandler mm[i] = new ........// you know what
```

I just thought these line are not very important to mention that's why made the mistake. But still the problem remains same.

**Edit-2:**

I get "array out of bound" type run time error. Let's say, array size is 6. So, last element is 5. But inside UpdateHandler "i" begins with 6 and throws an error. And I tried making "i" final, even made it global by declaring as a class field. I am trying to write short code examples here because it contains many codes. Better version is as follows:

```
public int i;//global declaration
//inside some method:
Sprite sprite[] = new Sprite[spriteArrayLength];
IUpdateHandler mm[] = new IUpdateHandler[spriteArrayLength];
for(i = 0; i < spriteArrayLength; i++){
    //many other actions
    mm[i] = new IUpdateHandler() {

       //do somthing with sprite array items
       float anyVar = sprite[i].getX();//problem rises here
    };
    sprite[i].registerUpdateHandler(mm[i]);
}
```

Comment: In your problem line, did you get compiling error about: i is not a final variable? 
Try adding a 'final int id = i;' inside the 'new IUpdateHandler(){}' block, and change to 'float anyVar = sprite[id].getX();'

Comment: No, actually I get "array out of bound" type run time error. Let's say, array size is 6. So, last element is 5. But inside UpdateHandler it "i" begins with 6 and throws an error. And I made "i" final, even made it global by declaring as a class field.

Comment: What you said is strange to me: 1. Non final local variable ( means `i` in your above code) can not be accessed in the anonymous inner class (means inside `new IUpdateHandler() {...}`), it can not be compiled. 2. You said you made `i` final, how can you do that with i++? It should not be compiled too.

Comment: Listen, I said, I made it global variable. I also tried final but it couldn't compile but I didn't mention that because I said I tried both final and global. See the edited form of my question. And these are not the issues.

Comment: @正宗白布鞋 You can try the codes I gave in Edit-2, you will see what I meant. But declare the variables globally. I wrote this in comments.

Comment: It is normal to get out of bound runtime exception by the current code, because your `i` is updated to `spriteArrayLength` after the for loop completed, so, every UpdateHandlers you created will all access to an invalid sprite. It seems that you want to access n-th sprite in the n-th UpdateHandler, then, you need to save a reference to index or sprite inside your IUpdateHandler for later accessing. This is what I recommend in the first comment above. (save a reference to the index of loop counter in the IUpdateHandler)

Comment: Yes, now you understand the problem. FYI, all the handlers will start functioning after the for loop ends. That's why they get max value of "i". I mentioned it in my question. I don't know how can I keep a reference of each element inside the handler. Can you show me a way? Thanks for your comments anyway.

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code in your Edit-2, my suggestion is:

```
Sprite sprite[] = new Sprite[spriteArrayLength];
IUpdateHandler mm[] = new IUpdateHandler[spriteArrayLength];
for(i = 0; i < spriteArrayLength; i++){
    //many other actions
    mm[i] = new IUpdateHandler() {

       private final int id = i; /* add this line */
       // call Log.i() here is compiling error

       @Override
       public void onUpdate(float pSecondElapsed) {
           //do somthing with sprite array items
           /* And access id, instead of i in below code. 
              Here, I assume this statement is located 
              within onUpdate() or reset().
            */
           float anyVar = sprite[id].getX();
       }

       @Override
       public void reset() {
       }
    };
    sprite[i].registerUpdateHandler(mm[i]);
}
```

Comment: BTW, because you omit some code in comment (//many other actions), you still need to make sure that you have executed appropriate Sprite constructor on each sprite[]...

Comment: Well, this way I am holding the initial value of "i" only. But it doesn't iterate. "i" Only gives 0 for each handler. And also, private is suggested as an illegal modifier. So, I removed it. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I can not connect the relationship between your comment and above my code.

Comment: Ok, if I add Log.i("aaa",""+id); after the line "private final int id = i;" I see all values are 0 for "id".

Comment: And also, I removed "private" because it doesn't support.

Comment: I will edit my answer to make it more clear. Because in my code, you can not call Log.i() after the line `private final int id = i`, it will cause compiling error... I would suggest you show where you call these code, and more detail in your UpdateHandler. And I don't know why `private` is illegal modifier, I use it very often in my inner anonymous class without problem.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was giving the line "private final int id = i" inside the onUpdate() method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the index variable `i` in 2 different contexts.

In your code you do this before the loop using `i` as an array index:

```
IUpdateHandler mm[i] = new ........// you know what
```

then inside the loop, you are changing the value of `i` and referencing `mm[i]` and `sprite[i]`.

I assume that you haven't correctly initialized the `mm` array to the correct size (`spriteArrayLength`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your update handler holds a reference to variable `i` but isn't evaluated until after the loop finishes.  Instead of holding a reference to `i`, give it a reference to the specific sprite, and for readability make it `final` to avoid any doubt that it could change:

```
for(i = 0; i < spriteArrayLength; i++){
    final Sprite currentSprite = sprite[i];

    //many other actions
    mm[i] = new IUpdateHandler() {
        //do somthing with sprite array items
        float anyVar = currentSprite.getX();
    };
    currentSprite.registerUpdateHandler(mm[i]);
}
```